# Loaded Kubuntu - No internet access

Tags: kubuntu, ethernet

I Loaded Kubuntu on my IMac 27 inch. But I cannot get on the internet. The internal Ethernet says it is connected. DHCP has given it an IP address and all looks good. However I cannot get on the Internet. I tried giving a static IP and nothing. Yet, I can see the IP address it was assigned when I hover over the Icon in the right lower corner.
Please help!
Thank you!
Errol....

Comment: Can you show us the output of `ifconfig` and a `traceroute` to 8.8.8.8?